# How can I rename the "Related Content" column that is used in workflows?

Tags: workflow, column

How can I rename the "Related Content" column that is used in workflows?  I want to call it something more intuitive for my users so they know to click on it to open the document something like "Click to Open Doc"

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use SharePoint Designer, open list you are interesting in, then click "Edit list columns".

[image: Edit list columns]

Comment: thanks, unfortunately it doesn't show up it is like it is a type of system field it doesn't want me to change.